# is it a stack overflow bug in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, overflow

I'm a novice in CS and I just tried to use recursion solve a change-making problem, which is mentioned in another question [Recursive change-making algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520263/recursion-python)

```
def change(total, coins):
    def coin_change(remain, position, changes=None):
        changes=[] if changes is None else changes
        if remain == 0:
            return len(changes), changes
        elif remain < 0 or position == -1:
            return float('inf'), changes
        else:
            strategy1 = coin_change(remain, position-1, changes)
            strategy2 = coin_change(remain-coins[position], position, 
                                    changes+[coins[position]])
        if strategy1[0] >= strategy2[0]:
            return strategy2
        else:
            return strategy1
    return coin_change(total, len(coins)-1, changes=None)
```

the code works well when given small inputs such as `(49, [1,5,12,24])`, but when the input gets larger, the code becomes very slow and when given the likely of `(1000, [1,5,12,24])`, errors pop up, just like this:

```
File "********\coin_change.py", line 56, in testperformance
function1(1480, [1, 7, 24, 42])
```

Though I have solved this problem by utilizing some dynamic programming techniques, I'm really curious about what's wrong with my initial codes. Is it a stack overflow problem? How does it happen? Hope some an explicit explication or reference materials.

Comment: What is the actual error? You've given us just the location of an unspecified error. But yes, it appears you are exceeding the maximum recursion depth of 1000.

Comment: The actual error information was an infinite loop of what I have posted, no other information showed up. So did you mean that recursion has a depth limit of 1000?

Comment: The Python interpreter, in order to avoid infinite recursion, will stop any recursion (even if it really would have completed) after 1000 recursive calls.